# How many synchronization objects can be used per process and per machine in Windows?

Tags: windows, synchronization

It's highly likely that there is a limitation on how many synchronization objects - semaphores, events, critical sections - can one process and all processes on a given machine use. What exactly is this limitation?

Comment: Raymond Chen's answer to that is: "If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong" (http://blogs.msdn.com/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx). I can imagine you're not asking because you're thinking about reaching that limit, but just in case some Googler gets here for the wrong reason...

Comment: I'm to develop a multiprocess application and need to select proper synchronization primitives. We've already hit the limit with exhausting the capacity of the thread message queue (used for PostThreadMessage()) and had to craft a workaround. This time I ask in advance.

Comment: http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2009/09/29/3283844.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For windows, the per-process limit on kernel handles(semaphores, events,mutex) is `2^24`.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724485(VS.85).aspx):

> Kernel object handles are process
>   specific. That is, a process must
>   either create the object or open an
>   existing object to obtain a kernel
>   object handle. The per-process limit
>   on kernel handles is **2^24**. However,
>   handles are stored in the paged pool,
>   so the actual number of handles you
>   can create is based on available
>   memory. The number of handles that you
>   can create on 32-bit Windows is
>   significantly lower than 2^24.

Comment: "Significantly lower than 2^24" could be 200 or could be 20k. I love MSDN for such statements.

Comment: @sharptooth: What did you expect to read? It says it depends on available memory, so that could be anything from 0 to ~2^24...

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the quota that is available for the process. I think in XP it is set to 10000 per process, but it can grow. I am not sure what the upper limit is.

Just checked it again, the 10000 limit is for the GDI handles and not for Kernel objects.